# How to compile TypeScript in a JS create-react-app project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, module

I have a react project created via create-react-app and written in JS. I have a vendor module that is written in TypeScript. Is there a way of importing this and have webpack bundle it without having to eject the project?

Comment: You need to some configuration.
Here is guide 

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

Comment: That's the problem I have in that without ejecting I don't have any config files.